# importance of mosque in reforming community

Tags: masjid

I have seen many Muslim in the mosque . they offer prayer and leave the mosque immdeiatly. In Pakistan people many have many problem which can be solved with community local interaction. And that can help to evolve a good Islamic community. But I have observed the mosque imams just keep on preaching for heaven and hell and remain concise to individualism . can we have reference with which we can preach Muslim that mosque is not only place for prayer by also for other activities which can help us to evolve collaboration, conflict resolution , local poverty reduction and last but not least a community service to build a healthy Muslim community platform

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain. Back at the Prophet time, the Masjid was built before his house was built. When Muslims used to conquer a country, the first thing they would do is build a Masjid first.

Masjid was meant to be the heart of the Muslim community. It would contain everything and everyone.

## The Masjid is a place for Poetry

In many instance poetry was recited in the Masjid for all, like what was [reported](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=1851&hid=677&pid=642485) that the prophet PBUH told Hassan Bin Thabet to compose a poet for the Quds to attack the occupiers. He even had him stand on his Minbar while reading the poetry.

## Masjid is the Military Complex

When the prophet would [order a war](http://audio.islamweb.net/audio/index.php?fuseaction=ft&ftp=hadeeth&id=7008212&spid=264), it would happen after the Jumma, where someone would take the war banner and lead the Muslims to war.

It was the place where the Prophet PBUH would discuss all Military issues in regards when/what/how.

## Masjid is a learning facility - a school

It is where most people would go to learn about their religion from the Prophet. This time it would be used for both general education and learning the deen.

## Masjid is a hospital

The Masjid can [be used as a hospital](http://audio.islamweb.net/audio/index.php?fuseaction=ft&ftp=athar&id=8001358&spid=264) to treat the wounded. When Saed Ben moud came to Madinah, was hit by an Arrow in the war of Khundak he was taken to the Masjid to be taken care of. He later died in it.

## Masjid is a shelter for those with no homes

It was [reported by Ibn Omar](http://audio.islamweb.net/audio/index.php?fuseaction=ft&ftp=hadeeth&id=7006903&spid=264) that: I was a single person, sleeping in the Masjid.

## You can talk in the Masjid

Opposed to what many [people think](http://audio.islamweb.net/audio/index.php?fuseaction=ft&ftp=hadeeth&id=7004914&spid=264). The masjid is the place to discuss worldy matters. There was a hadith saying:

> Talking in the Masjid eats the good deeds like fire eats wood.
>
> الكلام في المسجد يأكل الحسنات كما تأكل النار الحطب

However, this is a hadith rules by many as fake. Oppose there is a hadith Hassan that says:

> We used to talk after Fajir in the Masjid for the news of the Jahilia and the Prophet PBUH was with us and he would laugh and smile.
>
> كنا نتحدث بعد صلاة الفجر في المسجد بأخبار الجاهلية، والرسول صلى الله عليه وسلم معنا، فنضحك ويتبسم

## #

The list can go and on. The Masjid was meant as a City Hall for Muslims, however, many people now a days only reflect the Masjid as a place where even kids are not allowed to run around and scream and have fun. They expect everyone sitting down reading Quran or Praying. The Masjid was meant as something bigger than that.

Comment: But obviously everyone should obey and follow the respective rules of masjid like talking in low voice, no talk of Duniya etc.

Comment: @manetsus That is not the case, as I proved above from Hadith the prophet did talk about Duniya. You don't have to talk with low voice either, all of these "rules and regulations" are culturally made and have nothing to do with Islam, the commandments of Allah nor his Prophet PBUH. Think of the Masjid as a community center.

Answer (score 0):

The fast paced life has what caused your problem *"they offer prayer and leave the mosque immediately"*

> And those who respond to their Lord and keep up prayer, and **their rule is to take counsel among themselves**, and who spend out of what We have given them. (Qur'an 42:38.  More context [here](http://quran.com/42/35-41))

The verse just says "whose affairs are a matter of counsel" and like wise by other translators too, mostly implying to help in your case.

The companions of prophet Muhammad (pbuh) mostly used to decide matters, conduct affairs in a group.

More over, if you're in an Islamic state environment or in other words, if your community has got a Caliph/leader, inform him about the problems and he'll arrange a meeting sort of with the rest of the community.

If there is none, motivating the community by letting them know about the seriousness of the issue should help.

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't explain the role of mosque. They can take counsel among them self anywhere out of mosque which is causing decrement in the importance of mosque

Comment: whether it be within the boundary of mosque or outside the walls, sorting out things is more important than the place. And if that was your question, I don't remember any hadith which specifically talk about meetings being held **in mosques**.